# why I have 0 in my result? I don't know where it comes

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void ExhaustSet(const vector<int>& nums, 
                vector<vector<int>>& ans, int end) {
    if (end == nums.size()) {
        return;
    }
    if (end < 0) {
        ans.push_back({});
        ExhaustSet(nums, ans, end+1);
    }        
    auto ans_copy = ans;
    for (auto temp : ans_copy) {
        temp.push_back(nums[end]);
        ans.push_back(temp);
    }
    ExhaustSet(nums, ans, end+1);
}

vector<vector<int>> subsets(const vector<int>& nums) {
    if (nums.empty()) {
        return {};
    }       
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    ExhaustSet(nums, ans, -1);      
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    auto ans = subsets({1,2,3});
    for (const auto& e : ans) {
        cout<<"(";
        for (int num : e){
            cout<<num<<", ";
        }
        cout<<")\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code tries to find the power set of {1,2,3}, but this code has problems.
First, I do the debugging print:
() (1, ) (2, ) (1, 2, ) (3, ) (1, 3, ) (2, 3, ) (1, 2, 3, ) (0, )...
why I have 0 here?
Thank you!

Comment: You have `nums[end]`, where `end` can be `-1`. So you have undefined behavior, in your case it returns `0`. Probably you want to add `return` in `if (end < 0) {` branch.

Comment: good catch... Why I couldn't catch the error ... I've been spent quite a while.

Comment: Well, UB can be hard to find unless you know where to look at. I can tell how I reasoned: 0 is not one of numbers in the code, so let's check for "hidden" initialization (e.g. `vector<int> a(n)`, which creates vector of zeroes). There is nothing like this, so it's likely not a legitimate value, i.e. UB. The most common UB reason is out-of-bounds access, so let's checked array indexing, and here it is.

Comment: Probably that by learning how to use a debugger, you could figure out where the program does not works as you thinks in a few minutes. And you could start by trying even simpler data as 0, 1 or 2 items and fixes bugs before testing for larger data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the first step in your algorithm, when num == -1, the one that starts the recursive step:

```
void ExhaustSet(const vector<int>& nums, 
            vector<vector<int>>& ans, int end) {
    if (end == nums.size()) {
        return;
    }
    if (end < 0) {
        ans.push_back({});
        ExhaustSet(nums, ans, end+1);
// ** HERE YOU NEED A RETURN STATEMENT
    }        
    auto ans_copy = ans;
    for (auto temp : ans_copy) {
        temp.push_back(nums[end]);
        ans.push_back(temp);
    }
    ExhaustSet(nums, ans, end+1);
}
```

... so once your iterations end, you do one more step with -1 inside end, and nums[-1] it's invalid.

It's a miracle that the program does not crash.

```
void ExhaustSet(const vector<int>& nums, 
            vector<vector<int>>& ans, int end) {
    if (end == nums.size()) {
        return;
    }
    if (end < 0) {
        ans.push_back({});
        ExhaustSet(nums, ans, end+1);
        return;
    }        
    auto ans_copy = ans;
    for (auto temp : ans_copy) {
        temp.push_back(nums[end]);
        ans.push_back(temp);
    }
    ExhaustSet(nums, ans, end+1);
}
```